# How-to SELECT two tables in query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to get data of 'indication' from two different tables.

The script works fine when selecting FROM `number_one` only.

Did try this with a , inbetween but that doesn't work.

How should I do this?

```
query2 = mysql_query("SELECT `indication` FROM `number_one`, `number_two` ORDER BY `indication` DESC"); 
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($query2)){
if($explode2[1] == $row2->indication){
echo "<option value=\"$row2->indication\" selected=\"selected\">$row2->indication</option>";
}
else{
echo "<option value=\"$row2->indication\">$row2->indication</option>";
}
}
```

Solution

```
query2 = mysql_query("SELECT `indication` FROM `number_one` UNION ALL SELECT `indication` FROM `number_two` ORDER BY `indication` DESC"); 
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($query2)){
if($explode2[1] == $row2->indication){
echo "<option value=\"$row2->indication\" selected=\"selected\">$row2->indication</option>";
}
else{
echo "<option value=\"$row2->indication\">$row2->indication</option>";
}
}
```

Comment: so what is your desired output? and what you are getting now

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming you have two tables, `number_one` and `number_two` with the `indication` column, your query would cross-join the two tables, giving you a set of rows which each have two columns (`number_one.indication` and `number_two.indication`, in all the possible combinations.

If I understand the question correctly, you want to have them as **one column**, with all the values from both tables. This can be done using the `UNION ALL` set operator, as I demonstrate below:

```
SELECT indication
FROM ( SELECT indication
       FROM   number_one
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT indication
       FROM   number_two)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but I can bet it's because you just threw an answer up and didn't explain it. For the benefit of OP, this is called a subquery.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thnx!. I did find somethings about the UNION All, but didn't know how to put it in. Anyway after deleting the "1" in your solution before DESC it works.

Comment: @user2838753 - my pleasure. Please upvote or accept the answer to indicate it does indeed solve the issue.

Comment: Done. And how can I add the Table name in the option value? So you can see what indication is linked to what table?

Comment: if you want it as part of the value, you can `SELECT CONCAT('number_one.', indication)` instead of just select the `indication` from the table.

Comment: Yes, that works to show it in the select, but when I choose a option and save it, the database doesn't store it. So that doesn't work for me.